# Are rising temperatures making fires worse?

Tags: climate-change, fire, natural-disasters, al-gore

[Al Gore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Gore) [tweeted](https://twitter.com/algore/status/342317878827180033):

> Ferocious wildfire in California forces evacuation of ~3,000 [...] **Rising temperatures are making fires worse**. (Emphasis mine)

Is this true?

Comment: I think he means fires as in the forest fires. Higher temperature means more fires should start spontaneous, I assume he means it in that sense, not that individual fires get worse because of the higher temperatures.

Comment: @Wertilq Yes. I just added some context to show he was referring to wildfires.

Comment: So worse means MORE fires? BIGGER fires? What exactly is it?

Comment: @Wertilq I think we can assume he's using the plain meaning of the word: "*More harmful, painful, grievous, regrettable, unpleasant, offensive, unfavourable, unlucky, etc.*" (O.E.D.) More fires would be worse. Bigger fires would be worse.

Comment: This seems to be a logical conclussion tho, the higher the temprature the faster the forrest dries out. Dried grass/wood and such catches fire alot easier then wet grass/wood. Ofcourse if it was getting warmer but also wetter I would have my doubts.

Comment: The two answers neglect the changing forest management techniques, which have been blamed for making forests that burn more easily. Today's management is often a "let burn" policy, compared to spending every effort to stop them in the past.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Measuring forest-fire danger in northern Idaho](http://books.google.de/books?id=fU8I89WM9UEC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Fire%20correlation%20temperatures&source=bl&ots=tZqHgnjHU8&sig=DdbG4VCDdHSVMgqoQmc7q1bWgq4&hl=de&sa=X&ei=Un2vUdzlB6eF4ASxqYG4CQ&ved=0CIQBEOgBMAg4Cg#v=onepage&q=Fire%20correlation%20temperatures&f=false) mentioned a study made in Finland, which found a correlation.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, higher temperatures leads to more wild fires.**

[Article from a journal](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/927.full) says so:

> On page 940 of this issue, Westerling et al. (4) come to a similarly discomforting conclusion for wildfires. They show that warmer temperatures appear to be increasing the duration and intensity of the wildfire season in the western United States.[1](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/927.full)

[The paper it refers to](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/940.full) says:

> Spatial variability in the wildfire response to an earlier spring.
>   Vulnerability of western U.S. forests to more frequent wildfires due
>   to warmer temperatures is a function of the spatial distribution of
>   forest area and the sensitivity of the local water balance to changes
>   in the timing of spring.[2](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/940.full)

What Al Gore says thus have some back-up from the scientific community.

---

[1](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/927.full): Science 18 August 2006: Vol. 313, no. 5789, pp. 927-928 *Published Online July 6 2006* **Is Global Warming Causing More, Larger Wildfires?**

[2](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5789/940.full): Science 18 August 2006: Vol. 313, no. 5789, pp. 940-943 *Published Online July 6 2006*
**Warming and Earlier Spring Increase Western U.S. Forest Wildfire Activity**